# Python dict to csv

Tags: python

I have written a script to find image size and aspect ratio of all images in a directory along with their corresponding filepaths, I want to print dict values to csv file with following headers width,height,aspect-ratio and filepath

````
import os
import json
from PIL import Image

folder_images = "/home/user/Desktop/images"
size_images = dict()
def yocd(a,b): 
    if(b==0): 
        return a 
    else: 
        return yocd(b,a%b) 
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
        for path_image in filenames:
            if path_image.endswith(".png") or path_image.endswith('.jpg')  or path_image.endswith('.JPG') or path_image.endswith('.jpeg'):
                image = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, path_image))
                """ ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True """
                try:
                    with Image.open(image) as img:
                        img.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
                        img.verify()
                        print('Valid image')
                except Exception:
                        print('Invalid image')
                        img = False
                if img is not False:
                    width, heigth = img.size
                    divisor = yocd(width, heigth)
                    w = str(int(width / divisor))
                    h = str(int(heigth / divisor))
                    aspectratio = w+':'+h
                    size_images[image] = {'width': width, 'heigth': heigth,'aspect-ratio':aspectratio,'filepath': image}
for k, v in size_images.items():
    print(k, '-->', v) 
with open('/home/user/Documents/imagesize.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(size_images))```
````

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far to ahieve your goal? What failed? Reading the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section can help you understand that currently your question is not suited for SO.

Comment: To get the dictionary values in a csv file

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a (properly constructed) `dict` directly to a `pandas.DataFrame`.  Then, DataFrames have a `.to_csv()` function.

**Here are the docs:**

- [Pandas: Create a DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
- [Pandas: Write to CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without dependencies (but you may have to tweak the formatting)

```py
csv_sep = ';' # choose here wich field separatar you want
with open('your_csv', 'w') as f:
    # header
    f.write("width"+csv_sep"+height"+csv_sep"+aspect-ratio"+csv_sep+"filepath\n")
    # data
    for img in size_images:
        fields = [img['width'], img['height'], img['aspect-ratio'], img['filepath']]
        f.write(csv_sep.join(fields)+'\n')
```